# cascade static library link mechanism

Tags: c++, sdl-2, vcpkg

sdl2-image was built and installed as a static library `libSDL2_image.a`, it dependons on another static librarys, like webp, libpng, etc. When I link it like:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main
  SDL2::SDL2-static
  ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY}
)
```

It fails, showing error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/main.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o  -o main /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/libSDL2d.a /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libpng16.a /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/debug/lib/libSDL2_image.a /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libwebp.a /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libjpeg.a /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libpng16.a -lm -liconv -framework CoreVideo -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework ForceFeedback -framework Carbon -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -Wl,-undefined,error /Users/Ryan/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/lib/libz.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IMG_InitJPG", referenced from:
      _IMG_Init in libSDL2_image.a(IMG.c.o)
  "_IMG_InitPNG", referenced from:
      _IMG_Init in libSDL2_image.a(IMG.c.o)
  "_IMG_InitTIF", referenced from:
      _IMG_Init in libSDL2_image.a(IMG.c.o)
  "_IMG_Load", referenced from:
```

What happened?

And another question:

Give a static library libA.a, and libB.a which depends on libA.a. 
If I link a program with libB.a, do I have to also link with libA.a, e.g.

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main
  /path/to/libB.a
  /path/to/libA.a
)
```

Does it necessary? if and why?
And if libA.a has other dependencies and I don't know, what am I going to do?

Comment: vcpkg is for use with VC++. If you are not using `vcpkg integrate install` command you have to enter the *.lib files and *.h files manually.

Comment: I use the cmake toolchian: cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/Ryan/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake  ..

Comment: CMake used for building vcpkg.sln solution and later vcpkg.exe?  In static build  *. lib files are created in installed folder.

Comment: No use of Visual Studio, I'm in macOS command line: cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/Ryan/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake  .. && make -j4

Comment: vcpkg builds libraries for windows , not mac platform.

Comment: But the repo shows it support macOS and Linux now.

Comment: you're right, very recent development (24-4-18), saw on blog.

Comment: You should split your 2 questions. I don't follow what you're trying to do. Do you want to compile SDL2_image as a static lib?

Comment: The two questions are related. SDL2_image was compiled as a static library, when I build a main program and link it, link failed.

Comment: Can't reproduce on linux. You should check if resulting `libSDL2_image.a` have `IMG_LoadPNG`-like symbols, and if it isn't - it isn't an `SDL2_image` but some garbage. As for your second question - yes you have to recursively poll all dependencies. `.a` is just an archive of `.o`s; if having to specify libraries when linking object files is not surprising you then neither should `.a`.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you manage to solve this. I could not find anyone else having this problem